# Security flaws of Firebase

Tags: java, security, google-api, spring-security-oauth2

Bear with me, I might be wrong: I'm no security expert.

I believe I've been reading about how OAuth 2 does not prevent `replay-attacks`. What is the suggested way to prevent such events?

I also believe that leaving the JSON of `google-account-services.json`, used to validate credentials with Google for the Admin SDK, in our server-side project is a possible security flaw (`reverse engineering`).

What are the other known flaws of those system, and how could I improve the security of my system using them?

(I'm using Firebase-authentication to identify users to my servers, which uses Admin SDK.)

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Admin SDK has full administrative access to your Firebase project, and thus should only be used on a trusted server you control. It uses the credentials from `google-account-services.json` to authenticate with the Google servers.

All communication between the Admin SDK and the Google servers goes over encrypted connections, so can't be intercepted unless you set up a decrypting proxy yourself or hand out your SSL certificates.

Comment: Are there not ways to leak unwillingly parts of the JSON file? I thought I remembered reading about it (on reading, it is put in `/res/values/string` and that is accessible through decompiling, which I'm not sure if it's an option from someone working from outside the server). SSL is not what I consider to be the weak point.

Comment: The JSON file with the credentials that allows you to mint and verify tokens, is a different file from the `google-services.json` that is used by Android apps. The former gives complete administrative access to your project, while the latter merely contains project identifiers that your app needs to find its Firebase projects on the servers.

Comment: Ah, I mixed the android process with what happens on my JAVA server. So there is no way to leak any info about the JSON? (Consider we're hosting the server on `herokuapp`.)

Comment: That's hard to say: if someone gets access to your server, they'll have access to the credentials and thus to your project. But that is the case regardless of where you host it: you should only use it as a trusted environment if you can properly control access.

Comment: What about [this post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/firebase-separating-configuration-from-code-in-admin-sdk-d2bcd2e87de6) ? Why would people want to avoid exposing their Credentials if it isn't a threat ?